# I would like to use a buttons output in tkinter to answer an input in another function

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, input

This is a simple memory game, where the voice says a number, and you have to click the button with the same number. I want to use it with comparing lists. If you guessed correctly one the code will add another, and another and so on. My problem is, that I have the buttons and with the function button click I can define the values with print. I have the code where it should be linked, but I cannot lined them together. Please help me :)

```
import pyttsx3
import time
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("A little memory game")


sound_or_color = IntVar()  # for radiobutton 1, sound, 2 color
quiz_list = []  # this will be the random number
your_list = []  # this will get the input form the buttons
guess = StringVar()  # for the label to add guesses
best_score = 2
best_score_final = IntVar()
best_score_final.set(best_score)
actual_score_actual = IntVar()


def button_click(number):
    your_list.append(number)
    print(your_list)


def game():
   # if sound_or_color == 1:  # this will work with sound
    actual_score = 0
    global best_score
    while True:
        # this will generate the task, each round
        quiz_number = random.randint(1, 9)
        quiz_list.append(quiz_number)
        speaker = pyttsx3.init()
        speaker.say(quiz_list)
        speaker.runAndWait()
        print(quiz_list)
        guess.set("click your guess(es)")

        **# take the user's guess:
        for i in range(0, len(quiz_list)): 
            # your_list.append(int(input()))         <------the problematic part
            button_click()**

        # was the guess right?
        if quiz_list == your_list:
            actual_score += 1
            actual_score_actual.set(actual_score)
            your_list.clear()

        else:
            end_text = "Coungratulation, your score is", actual_score
            your_list.clear()
            quiz_list.clear()
            speaker2 = pyttsx3.init()
            speaker2.say(end_text)
            speaker2.say("Click the start button, to play again")
            speaker2.runAndWait()
            if actual_score > best_score:
                best_score = actual_score
                best_score_final.set(best_score)
            break



# labels:
label_best = tk.Label(root, text="best score: ",
                      textvariable=best_score_final, fg="#900C3F")
label_score = tk.Label(root, text="actual score: ",
                       textvariable=actual_score_actual, fg="#07A0F1")
label_best2 = tk.Label(root, text="best score: ", fg="#900C3F")
label_score2 = tk.Label(root, text="actual score: ", fg="#07A0F1")
label_input = tk.Label(root, textvariable=guess)

# define buttons:
button_start = Button(root, text="Start",
                      command=game, bg="#65B9E5")

button_0 = Radiobutton(root, text="with sound",
                       variable=sound_or_color, value=1)
button_10 = Radiobutton(root, text="with color",
                        variable=sound_or_color, value=2)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20,
                  command=lambda: button_click(9))

# Put buttons on the screen
label_input.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_10.grid(row=4, column=1)
button_start.grid(row=4, column=2)

label_score2.grid(row=5, column=0)
label_best2.grid(row=5, column=1)
label_score.grid(row=6, column=0)
label_best.grid(row=6, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Will the user type in the answer, or will he choose an option out of the ones listed?

Comment: my idea is to chose a button, click it, and the number should be the input